# Unable to find package Xamarin.LiveReload. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I am getting this error using Xamarin Live Reload install on my test app, so when i try to build my app on App Center:

```
Errors in         /Users/vsts/agent/2.149.2/work/1/s/TestApp/TestApp.Android/TestApp.Android.csproj
NU1101: Unable to find package Xamarin.LiveReload. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org

My Reference for this package point to this site it is not point to nuget package.
```

Any tips & tricks to solve this.

Resources:

Xamarin Live Reload
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinLiveReload#qna

AppCenter
https://appcenter.ms/apps

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/247

Comment: Thanks fror the link, but as i wrote, when i am try to build my app using this feature included in AppCenter a get the error, but thanks for your help.

Comment: the github issue explains the proper source to use for the package, you should be able to use a nuget.config file to tell AppCenter that